# template specialization function parameter count

Tags: c++, templates

Ok, an update to my previous question about templates ( I'm such a noob on this field )...
I resumed most of my questions to:
Is it possible to have a different parameter count for a member function, depending on the template parameter used on the class declaration?

For example, a constructor:

```
template <typename Type, unsigned ElementCount>
class TVector
    {
    public:
    Type Values[ElementCount];

    TVector ( ElementCount number of Type here )
        { ...
```

Is this possible?
Or perhaps a setter:

```
SetValues ( ElementCount number of Type here );
```

EDIT:
Ok, my mistake, i did not explain fully.
This vector is a trigonometry vector, not an array of elements. So, it should support 2, 3 or 4 values.

As for the constructor, i wanted to be able to do something like:
    TVector  xpto ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

As for compiler, i'm using gcc, and dunno if it's safe to enable more recent c++ standards. It does complain about it, when i enable them. So, no enable_if for me :)

Thanks.

Comment: You're basically making [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). It is an aggregate type, so can make use of aggregate initialisation. You could do the same, or there's no reason you couldn't have your constructor take an `std::initializer_list` or some other container.

Comment: I meant vector as in 2D, 3D or 4D vector. Algebra.

Comment: @RhiakathFlanders: You can still delegate to std::array for many functions- including this one. Just have it as your sole data member (public) and don't define any constructors/etc yourself. That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The member function can have as parameter a `std::initializer_list<T>` type that will let it access any number of objects of type const T. In that case, ElemCount, in the class template, can be removed as you don't have to specify number of arguments.

```
template <typename Type>
class TVector
    {
    public:    

    TVector ( std::initializer_list<Type> l )
        { ...
```

Comment: He does need it for the internal array.

Comment: that requires me to enable c++11, which is something i was trying to avoid... I'm beginning to think most of what i want is possible, only if i adhere to extensions, or more recent updates to the standard, instead of the standard c99. GCC complains that support for c++11 is still experimental, so...

Comment: also, i've seen in several places to avoid linking libs compiled with c++99 with ones compiled with c++11. As i'm linking to some other libs, this could be a problem..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using `std::enable_if`.

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct AllSameAsT : public std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct AllSameAsT<T> : public std::true_type
{
};

template <typename T, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct AllSameAsT : public AllSameAsT<T, Ts...>
{
};


template <typename Type, unsigned ElementCount>
class TVector
    {
    public:
    template <typename ... Ts, typename = std::enable_if_t<AllSameAsT<Type, Ts...>::value && (sizeof...(Ts) == ElementCount)>
    TVector (Ts... ts);
    };
```

If you don't have C++14, you would also need to add

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;
```

As JosephMansfield has pointed out in the comments, a simpler solution might be to just accept an `std::array<Type, ElementCount>`.

Comment: A constructor with 4 parameters will accept trigonometry vectors of all sizes.

Just initialize the parameter values to zero.

`TVector( T t1=(T)0, T t2=(T)0, T t3=(T)0, T t4=(T)0 ) { 
}`

Ignore the zeros in your calculation when a trigonometry vector is less than 4.